# Add button to Internet Explorer toolbar during run time

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++

I am currently create a simple additional button to my Internet Explorer 7, toolbar. The button works. I am using Visual C++.

But now, I would like to create a to create a button during my Internet Explorer is running. Means, on certain condition, my program (a dll registered with regsvr32) will add a button to the toolbar. and after certain condition, the button also can be disappeared.

How can I achieve this?

update:

I tried using this line:

```
ShowWindow(hWndButton, SW_HIDE);
```

It hides my Internet Explorer browser. Under Task Manager, it is still running. How to make it hide only the button object?

edit:

I want to modify this code..

```
    STDMETHODIMP CButtonDemoBHO::Exec(const GUID*, DWORD nCmdID, DWORD d, VARIANTARG*, VARIANTARG* pvaOut){
ATLTRACE("CButtonDemoBHO::Exec\n");

switch (nCmdID){
case BUTTON_PRESSED:

MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have pressed the button", L"Button Pressed", MB_OK);

    <------- I would like to hide the button here.

    break;
case MENU_ITEM_SELECT:
MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have simulated a button press with the menu ", L"Menu Pressed", MB_OK);
    break;
   }
  return S_OK;
 }
```

Comment: You say "the button works" - that means that **you** have created the button - correct? How are you creating it?

Comment: yes. The button is registered using regsvr32. But, by default I want it to hide, and after certain condition inside my cpp program, the button will appear.

Comment: First of all: regsvr32 registers the **BHO** not the **button**. See my new edited answer for the actual solution to your problem...

Comment: it seems that i could not find the exact location to put the show/hide function. when i call hide function under CButtonDemoBHO::Exec, the whole browser closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add the button always (as you are now), but hide it/unhide it when you want it seen?

**Edited to add:**

To hide the button, you need to use `ShowWindow()`. Here are two ways:

1. If the button is a `CButton`, call `theButton.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`
2. If the button is a plain window, call `ShowWindow(hWndButton, SW_HIDE)`

**Edited again:**

I found the source code you're trying to modify: [forum-assist](http://code.google.com/p/forum-assist/).

Basically, whichever class defines the button, or knows how to find it (probably `RebarHandler.cpp`) is where you should add methods to show and hide the button. Then you have to call that from `CButtonDemoBHO::Exec()`.

I can't tell you how to get from `CButtonDemoBHO` to `CRebarHandler` without analyzing the whole project.

Comment: This is also ok. but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: This button resides on the IE toolbar. Which one should I use?

Comment: How can I tell that the button is either a CButton or a plain window?